# custom animation does not wrk for fragment

Tags: android, animation, fragment

## homefragementActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.dk.view.folder.ResideMenu;


    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        private View parentView;
        private ResideMenu resideMenu;
        ImageView imagef;
        public Animation objani;




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
            setUpViews();
            try {

                RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
                ImageView imagef = (ImageView) r1.findViewById(R.id.imageViewu);
                objani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                        R.anim.asd);
                imagef.startAnimation(objani);

            }

            catch(Exception ae)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ae.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return parentView;


        }



        private void setUpViews() {
            MenuActivity parentActivity = (MenuActivity) getActivity();
            resideMenu = parentActivity.getResideMenu();



            parentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_open_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
                }
            });




            }

        }
}
```

### This is my homefragmnt.java file here i want to animate Imageview

into fade in(animation) but my program does not work

#   here is the xml code of home.xml it is the xml code of homefragment.java..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/r1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/l1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewu"
            android:src="@drawable/gesture"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" 1. Swipe right/left to open menu"
            android:textColor="#ffacacac"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_open_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Play!!!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## and here is the fade in(animation) xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: `"but my program does not work"` because you have a bug in your program

Comment: plz help me sir, tll me what is that bug?how can i fix it?

Comment: no one can tell with such problem description: `"but my program does not work"`

Comment: sir all these code where executing without any error but there is no animation in ma fragment page

Comment: i have givn animation(fade in) for the image view within try catch block

Comment: RelativeLayout r1=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
                ImageView imagef = (ImageView) r1.findViewById(R.id.imageViewu);
                objani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                        R.anim.asd);
                imagef.startAnimation(objani);

Comment: please help me with the code

Comment: you are inflating `R.layout.home` but you are not adding that layout to any container, so how is it to show any animation?

Comment: sir plz help me to just animate a fade in(custom animation) tio a Image in image view sir,

Comment: you are inflating R.layout.home but you are not adding that layout to any container, so how is it to show any animation? use `hierarchyviewer` to see your ui tree

Comment: im new to android and i have neva have used a hierarchy viewer sir,can uplz rewrite my code sir,it will be soo usefull to me,plz

Comment: can iuse image canvas on fragmnt to do animation?

Comment: is there any other option plz help sir\

Comment: Can i use image canvas